# Ant deploy WAR file to tomcat server failure

Tags: tomcat, ant

I am having a little trouble getting my deployment task in ant to function.  I have a war file that is generated as part of the build process, and I am now trying to autodeploy that to my test server.  In ant I have defined a deployment task as seen below.  When I try to run it I get a file not found error on the server in the catalina.out log file.  Does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong that is causing this deploy to not function?  I have checked the path, and it is correct and the WAR file exists. Thanks

username="${lamp.user}"

password="${lamp.password}"

update="true"

path="/beam"
   localWar="file:${module.beam.basedir}\out\war\beam.war" />

Comment: I wonder if the fact that you are using different file separators in `path` and `localWar` has anything to do with it.

Comment: path I believe should be the tomcat context path, while localWar is the location of the war file to be deployed.  At least that is how it appears in the examples that I have seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is caused by using localWar instead of war in the build target. By replacing localWar with war it correctly deploys to the remote server.  It appears that localWar would be used if ant is being run from the same machine as the tomcat server.